# The Composition of Functions

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Say $f(x)= \sqrt{2x + 2}$
Domain here would be limited to values of $x$ greater than or equal to $-1$. 
$g(x)=(2x^2)+3$ (arbitrary, really)
$g(f(x))$ would have no restrictions on domain despite $f(x)$ having restrictions, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's not correct.

First of all, Domain of $f$ consists of $x \geq -1$. $g\circ f$ will also have this domain restriction, as plugging any number less than $-1$ in $f$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: To elaborate on the second part: Just because we have a nice expression $2(2x+2)+3$ that happens to conicide with $g(f(x))$ whenever $f(x)$ is defined, does not mean that the function $g\circ f$ is defined at points where not even $f$ is defined.

Comment: One might say: "the composition can be extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$", but the composition itself is not defined everywhere.